# First and surn name regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I wrote a Regex to match first / last name for a registration form in my web site.
The requirements are:

- Up to 44 chars
- `-` or `'` are acceptable
- One space is acceptable within the names
- Unicode is not required

Is there any way to make my expression shorter?

```
^[a-zA-Z]{2,12}['-]?[a-zA-Z]{1,10}\s?[a-zA-Z]{2,12}['-]?[a-zA-Z]{1,10}$
```

Is it too much restrictions for a name field?

Comment: Your solution (or any solution) is bound to fail. And nothing more annoying than having a "invalid" real name. So short answer: don't try it. :)

Comment: Any example for a possible fail? I'm feeling like I covered most cases..

Comment: In your requirements you state that "One space is acceptable within the names". My name is "PeeHaa von Trappenhauskraftwagen bis Glühwein".

Comment: And mine is Al Salam Bin Laden, or Albert Åberg? Why on earth would you need to restrict a users name anyway ?

Comment: First of all my condolences about your name ;) Should I add one more space and it will be better? BTW Bin Laden is a surn name :)

Comment: @adeneo has a very good question: why do you need to restrict a user's name? What is a user supposed to do if his/her name doesn't meet your restrictions? http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: You should read [Personal Name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_name) thoroughly before trying to form a format of names. My name is "A K M Mokaddim Shiplu". Most website just address me like "Dear A"!

Comment: @KeithThompson - Should'nt I use regex to check the incoming form values to protect my web from injection? (In addition to the common SQL filters)

Comment: Checking for "valid" names and blocking SQL injection are two *very* different problems. In principle, there's nothing wrong with the name in [this XKCD cartoon](http://xkcd.com/327/). Ideally, you should be able to accept it *as a name* without treating it as SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First with your regex the response is up to 47 chars : 12+1+10+1+12+1+10.

I think the best way for you is to allow 44 chars from letters, coma, minus or white space.

You can force the first char to be a letter :

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\-'\s]{0,43}$
```

Comment: I like your regex more than mine.. I'll take it - how much? ;) Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't first letter be always Capital?

Comment: No there is name like von... de... , and as said Keith Thompson, all your your conceptions about names are false...

Answer (score 0):

Here is what names your code might miss:

```
Jo Blow                  not passed
Hyoung Kyoung Wu         not passed
Mike O'Neal              not passed
d'Are to Beaware         not passed
O Henry Smith            not passed
Mathais d'Arras          not passed
Martin Luther King Jr    not passed
George De FunkMaster     not passed
Kurtis B-Ball Basketball not passed
Ahmad el Jeffe           not passed
An Ni                    not passed
```

You can try this one that can handle almost all names

```
^[^- '](?=(?![A-Z]?[A-Z]))(?=(?![a-z]+[A-Z]))(?=(?!.*[A-Z][A-Z]))(?=(?!.*[- '][- ']))[A-Za-z- ']{2,}$
```

```
Jo Blow                      passed
Hyoung Kyoung Wu             passed
Mike O'Neal                  passed
d'Are to Beaware             passed
O Henry Smith                passed
Mathais d'Arras              passed
Martin Luther King Jr        passed
George De FunkMaster         passed
Kurtis B-Ball Basketball     passed
Ahmad el Jeffe               passed
An Ni                        passed
```